# How to remove elements that were fetched using querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, element, selectors-api

This seems like something that would have a quick answer, but I can't find one. Maybe I'm searching the wrong terms? No libraries please, though I don't need cross-browser fallbacks, I'm targeting all the latest versions on this project.

I'm getting some elements:

```
element = document.querySelectorAll(".someselector");
```

This is working, but how do I now delete these elements? Do I have to loop through them and do the `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);` thing, or is there a simple function I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think any of these answers get at what the OP is asking. All answers are great answers for removing the element from the DOM, but not the list of elements returned from querySelectAll(). If you run `elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0])`, element[0] is removed from the DOM but not from `elements`. The OP (and myself) is looking for a way to do something like `elements.slice(1)` (if elements was an array rather than a `NodeListOf`). Is there a way to remove elements from a `NodeListOf` object or do we have to call `querySelectorAll()` after calling `remove()` on the element?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes, you're almost right. `.querySelectorAll` returns a *frozen NodeList*. You need to iterate it and do things.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( element, function( node ) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
});
```

Even if you only got one result, you would need to access it via index, like

```
elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
```

---

If you only *want* to query for one element, use `.querySelector` instead. There you just get the *node reference* without the need to access with an index.

Comment: @jAndy thanks for the answer. I need to remove the first node of the NodeList. Is there any way to directly remove the first node?

Comment: Well, you can simply call `elementsList[ 0 ].remove();` in todays DOM API.

Answer (score 95):

Since the `NodeList` already supports the `forEach` you can just use:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".someselector").forEach(e => e.remove());
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="someselector">element 1</span>
  <span class="someselector">element 2</span>
  there shouldn't be any of the above "element" spans after you run the code
</div>
```

See the [NodeList.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and [Element.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

**Internet Explorer support**. IE does not support the `forEach` on the `NodeList` and IE also doesn't support `remove` method on `Element` objects. Hence, if you also wish to run the above code in the IE, just add the following lines at the beginning of your JavaScript code, and to remove an element use the [Node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) instead (o*r use the [Element.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) polyfill*):

```js
if (!NodeList.prototype.forEach && Array.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
// ..then continue as usual with the forEach
document.querySelectorAll(".someselector").forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="someselector">element 1</span>
  <span class="someselector">element 2</span>
  Should be empty
</div>
```

Answer (score 30):

Even more concise with [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [ChildNode.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.someselector')).forEach(el => el.remove());
```

Ok, just saw NodeList is iterable so it can be done even shorter:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.someselector').forEach(el => el.remove());
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.someselector').forEach(el => el.remove());`
This line works amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the element from querySelectorall() by using remove() function. make sure remove function can only be used in modern browser.

```
// Fetch the elements to remove
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.class-name');

// Iterate through the elements and remove them
elements.forEach(element => {
  element.remove();
});
```

reference - https://bbbootstrap.com/code/remove-elements-that-were-fetched-using-queryselectorall-10186399