# Remove all table rows except one with a given class

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I have a table rendered dynamically. There's one `<tr class="dolly">` somewhere inside its `<tbody>` that serves as a reference row - it gets cloned and filled with data later. I need to delete all rows except that one.

### What I tried:

- **`for` loop**: uses an increment which quickly gets invalid as the rows are deleted
- **`while` loop**: continues until all rows are deleted, which never happens because of the condition

Please let me know if you have any ideas. Please no jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.dolly)')` to select all `tr's` except with class `.dolly` and then iterate over it to remove the filtered `tr's`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table tr:not(.dolly)').forEach((tr) => {
    tr.remove();
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="dolly">
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There [seems to be an even slightly shorter option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54343121/722036). Either way, that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna share my solution here.

```
function deleteAllOtherRowExceptOne(exceptionIndex) {
  const tableBody = document.querySelector('#my-table-tbody')
  const tableBodyRowLength = tableBody.rows.length

  let deleteIndex = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < tableBodyRowLength; i++) {
    if(i == exceptionIndex){
      deleteIndex++
    } else {
      tableBody.deleteRow(deleteIndex)
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this question.

```
// Fetch all rows
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

// Iterate through the rows and remove those that do not have the desired 
class
const className = 'class-name';
   rows.forEach(row => {
     if (!row.classList.contains(className)) {
       row.remove();
    }
});
```

I took refernce from here - https://bbbootstrap.com/code/delete-all-table-rows-except-one-given-class-javascript-61232938